# should i install ubuntu 14.04 or wait for 15.04

Tags: 14.04

my question as the title said, should I install Ubuntu (14.04.2 LTS) now ? Or should I wait for the 15.04 ?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: This will probably get closed as "opinionated" since this is totally up to you. The official stance: do NOT use 15.04 if you depend on your software to work. I have been using 15.04 2 months now and it is as stable as ever though ;)

Answer (score 2):

the good thing is you should install ubuntu 14.04 as it is a long term support(lts) release, which means your computer will get the required updates and bug fixes and is more stable and on the other hand ubuntu 15.04 is the isn't the lts and it is in the current development and it is more likely you will have less stable desktop environment than ubuntu 14.04